# Any "reasonable" and "natural" false graph theory conjectures for which the Petersen graph is not a counterexample?

Tags: graph-theory, big-list, conjectures

I heard that the Petersen graph is a good test of a graph theory conjecture. As in, if you want to know whether a graph theory conjecture is false, the Petersen graph is likely to be a counterexample. So, with that in mind, are there any "reasonable" and "natural" graph theory conjectures, which is false, but for which the Petersen graph is NOT a counterexample? I would like a list of several such conjectures. Note, I do not have a formal definition of "reasonable" or "natural", but I know it when I see it.

Comment: Any false conjecture about planar graphs, for example, will vacuously do the job since Petersen isn't planar. Any conjecture first falsified by a "large" graph (e.g. >10 vertices) will similarly do the job. I think this question is far too broad (and really stems from taking a quick heuristic far too seriously).

Comment: The simplest such statement is the false conjecture that every $3$-regular graph has a perfect matching. In fact, this is only true for bridgeless $3$-regular graphs by (ironically) Petersen's theorem.